# Coordinate Ring of Algebraic Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite  field and  $X$,  $Y$ two algebaric varieties over $\mathbb F$. Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be the coordinate ring of $X$ and $Y$,respectively. If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are not isomorphic can we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ have not the same number of points?

Comment: Do you mean $F$-valued points? But in any interpretation of your question the answer is No, of course. Otherwise algebraic geometry would be boring (same number of points would give isomorphism).

Comment: For a simple example, pick two ideals that result in $X, Y$ empty, but with coordinate rings that are different.

Comment: Yes, I mean $\mathbb F$ valued points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple example, let the ground field be the field with three elements, $\mathbb{F}_2$.  Consider the two subvarieties of the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ given by $X = V(0)$ (the entire affine line) and $Y = V(x(x-1))$ (the union of the two points $0$ and $1$).

Both $X$ and $Y$ have two $\mathbb{F}_2$-rational points, but they are not isomorphic varieties.  In fact, $X$ is an irreducible curve, while $Y$ is a (reducible) collection of two distinct points.  So even crude invariants such as dimension and irreducibility are not preserved under the relation "have the same number of $\mathbb{F}$-rational points".

The way to tell these two varieties apart is to look at their $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$-rational points for $k > 1$.  Indeed, $X$ has $2^k$ $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$-rational points, while $Y$ has just $2$ $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ rational points.  If $X$ and $Y$ were isomorphic as $\mathbb{F}_2$-varieties, they would have the same number of $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$-rational points for all $k \geq 1$.